# create phonegap plugin with libxml2 dependency

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova, libxml2, icenium

i am trying to create plugin as described. the plugin should use static lib that i create which depends on `libxml2`.

I have added `libxml2.dylib` to `plugin.xml` as described in phonegap plugin spec page there is also need to set header search paths to `/usr/include/libxml2`. I know I can do this manually in Xcode but since this plugin is going to be use in telerik app builder platform i wonder if there is a better way?

I have searched for maybe a compiler flag which tell xcode to use `/usr/include/libxml2` but it fails.

Any ideas are appreciated.